# Huggingface - time out or connection error

Tags: python, huggingface

I want to use LLaMA and OPT via the Hugging Face API. However, I always get the same two error messages. Either

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

Or

{'error': 'Model decapoda-research/llama-65b-hf time out'}

This is my code:

```
import requests

API_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/decapoda-research/llama-65b-hf"
headers = {"Authorization": ###}

def query(payload):
    response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
    return response.json()

output = query({"inputs": "Once upon a time ","options":{"wait_for_model":True},})

print(output)
```

What am I doing wrong or what can I do to actually access the models?